# ActiveRecord where query on grandchildren's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
User has_many Plans
Plan has_many PlanDates
PlanDates has an attr :ddate that is a Date
week = [Array of dates in a given week]
```

Given that, I'd like help constructing a query that finds all the unique `user_ids` of Users who have any Plan that has any PlanDate in a given week.

So far I have this:

```
week_users = User.joins(plans: :plan_dates).where.not(id: 246).where("plans.plan_dates.ddate >= ?", week.first).where("plans.plan_dates.ddate <= ?", week.last).uniq

=> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "plan_dates"
LINE 1: ..." = "plans"."id" WHERE ("users"."id" != 246) AND (plans.plan...
                                                         ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "plan_dates", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
: SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "plans" ON "plans"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "plan_dates" ON "plan_dates"."plan_id" = "plans"."id" WHERE ("users"."id" != 246) AND (plans.plan_dates.ddate >= '2015-11-02') AND (plans.plan_dates.ddate <= '2015-11-06')
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Try `week_users = User.joins(plans: :plan_dates).where.not(id: 246).where("plan_dates.ddate >= ?", week.first).where("plan_dates.ddate <= ?", week.last).uniq`

Comment: that worked thanks! i didn't realize you didn't need the association in the where. if you post as answer i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for
>   table "plan_dates"

The below should work

```
week_users = User.joins(plans: :plan_dates).where.not(id: 246).where("plan_dates.ddate >= ?", week.first).where("plan_dates.ddate <= ?", week.last).uniq
```

You can also simplify it to below

```
week_users = User.joins(plans: :plan_dates).where.not(id: 246).where(plan_dates: { ddate: week.first..week.last }).uniq
```